# xsl:count doesn't count right in xsl:value-of select

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to count flocus specie number in this xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<nuages>
   <nuage>
      <nom>altocumulus 
        <espece>lenticularis</espece>
        <espece>stratiformis</espece>
        <espece>castellanus</espece>
        <espece>flocus</espece>
      </nom>
      <altitude max="6000" min="2000" />
      <hydrometeores>Aucun.</hydrometeores>
   </nuage>
</nuages>
```

I have tried this:

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="count(/nuages/nuage[espece='flocus'])" />
```

but it always returns 0

Comment: Are you sure that's how your XML is structured? With `nom` being the parent node of all `espece` elements, and the text node `"altocomulus"` being their sibling?

Comment: yes its an exercice that I have to do for school but I can't find how

Comment: What Michael means: `<xsl:value-of select="count(/nuages/nuage/nom[espece='flocus'])" />` returns 1.

Comment: I have cut the xml file due to post max length

Comment: IMHO, the closing tag of `</nom>` is misplaced. If I am mistaken, then Tomalak gave you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/nuages/nuage/nom/espece[.='flocus'])" />
```

But I'm not entirely sure (because of the limitations of my French and your English).

Answer (score 0):

Answering on the assumption that your XML code is correct:

If you change your XPath expression to the one suggested by @Tomolak `count(/nuages/nuage/nom[espece='flocus'])`, you will get `1` as a result.

But the more likely approach is that you want to count the species which are on the same level of the [taxonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomy_(biology)).
In that case, use

```
count(/nuages/nuage/nom[espece='flocus']/espece)
```

which result is `4`.